# Trying to pass multiple parameters from php to javascript

Tags: javascript, php

Heres my current code in php with one parameter which works

```
 <?php
  $sid = "012";
  echo '<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="changeConfirmed('.$sid.')">';

?>
```

Now im trying to pass two parameters or more, but cant seem to get it to work, here is my attempt:

```
 <?php
  $name="abc
  $sid = "012";
  echo '<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="changeConfirmed('.$sid.','.$name.')">';

?>
```

Comment: can you post the  `changeConfirmed` function definition too?

Comment: "cant seem to get it to work" is an insufficient problem description. Please clearly state what you would expect and what the result is instead. Edit the question to include the `changeConfirmed` function and possibly any error that is triggered.

Answer (score 3):

You need quotes around the parameters or javascript treats them like variables instead of strings.

```
echo '<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="changeConfirmed(\''.$sid.'\',\''.$name.'\')">';
```

Answer (score 2):

If one of your JavaScript function parameters is a string, you'll have to correctly enclose it in quotes:

```
<?php
  $name="abc";
  $sid = "012";
  echo '<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="changeConfirmed('.$sid.',\''.$name.'\')">';
?>
```

You get away with $sid not enclosed in quotes because it looks like a number.